# Parse a file to match certain pattern and return subsequent lines having different pattern

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a log file and I am trying to parse the file in following way:

The file to be parsed looks like:

```
filename.......f1
This test is associated with file 1 - ignore it
filename.......f2
This test is associated with file 2 -ignore it
filename.......f3
This test is associated with file 3 - line 1 - do not ignore it
This test is associated with file 3 - line 2 - do not ignore it
filename.......f4
This test is associated with file 4 - ignore it
filename.......f5
This test is associated with file 5 - do not ignore it
```

Let's suppose we are macthing the text in file using Regx pattern as follows:

```
MATCHING_PATTERN1 - for "filename.......f[X]"
MATCHING_PATTERN2 - for "This test is associated with file [X] - do not ignore it"
```

I'm using following code:

```
package org.c2pfiscbk.tutorial;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestLogParser {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LogParser lp = new LogParser();
        lp.logReader();

    }

}

class LogParser {

    public void logReader(){
        File input = new File("file_location/fileName.log");
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);

            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                String dLine = scanner.nextLine();
                if (dLine.matches("MATCHING_PATTERN1")){
                    System.out.println(dLine);
                }
                else{
                    if (dLine.matches("MATCHING_PATTERN2")){
                            System.out.println(dLine);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

My output using above code is:

```
filename.......f1
filename.......f2
filename.......f3
This test is associated with file 3 - line 1 - do not ignore it
This test is associated with file 3 - line 2 - do not ignore it
filename.......f4
filename.......f5
This test is associated with file 5 - do not ignore it
```

Whereas, my requirment is:

```
filename.......f3
This test is associated with file 3 - line 1 - do not ignore it
This test is associated with file 3 - line 2 - do not ignore it
filename.......f5
This test is associated with file 5 - do not ignore it
```

Which means I am intrested only in the filenames (with MATCHING_PATTERN1) followed by certain text (with MATCHING_PATTERN2) along with the text (with MATCHING_PATTERN2) itself.

I don't want to use sed or egrep or any other external tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a boolean variable to say whether you need to print the first match (since you only want to print it once for all the associated pattern 2's). Then as the answers above suggest, you can then use a cache style variable to print the file name once.

```
String fileName=null;
boolean printFilename = false;    
while(scanner.hasNext()){
   String dLine = scanner.nextLine();
   if (dLine.matches("MATCHING_PATTERN1")){
       fileName = dLine;
       printFilename = true;
   }
   else{
       if (dLine.matches("MATCHING_PATTERN2")){
            if (printFilename) {        
                System.out.println(fileName);
                printFilename = false;
            }
            System.out.println(dLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks You! it's working perfectly as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Simply store the filename in some variable and print it only when you are in the

```
String fileName=null;
while(scanner.hasNext()){
   String dLine = scanner.nextLine();
   if (dLine.matches("MATCHING_PATTERN1")){
       fileName = dname;
   }
   else{
    if (dLine.matches("MATCHING_PATTERN2")){
        System.out.println(fileName );
        System.out.println(dLine);
     }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank You! Nadir. Sorry to not specifying it in my question but I did tried this earlier and it have a different problem. This will return the output such that with every new "MATCHING_PATTERN2" output of "MATCHING_PATTERN1" will get printed. I.e. "filename.......f3" will get printed twice for every "MATCHING_PATTERN2". I hope you got my point.

Comment: @Nadir, this will not work, as `pattern1` will get printed every time `pattern2` is matched

Answer (score 0):

Well your output is logical, since the first match makes it print any "filename.... f[X]", including the ones you don't want.  Make the first match store the line in a variable instead or printing it, print that variable in the second match if it's not printed yet and it'll work as you want:

```
        String cacheLine = "";
        String lastPrintedCacheLine = "";
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            String dLine = scanner.nextLine();
            if (dLine.matches("MATCHING_PATTERN1")){
                cacheLine = dLine;
            } else if (dLine.matches("MATCHING_PATTERN2")){
                if (! cacheLine.equals(lastPrintedCacheLine)) {
                    System.out.println(cacheLine);
                    lastPrintedCacheLine = cacheLine;
                }
                System.out.println(dLine);
            }
        }
```

Verified.  However, the answer from [Riggy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37347051/6178459) works as well and costs less.

Note that your use of the {} block after the `else` is obsolete and you could simply use `else if`.  Makes the code a little less messy imho.

Comment: this will not work, as `pattern1` will get printed every time `pattern2` is matched

Comment: Thank You! Arjan. Sorry to not specifying it in my question but I did tried this earlier and it have a different problem. This will return the output such that with every new "MATCHING_PATTERN2" output of "MATCHING_PATTERN1" will get printed. I.e. "filename.......f3" will get printed twice for every "MATCHING_PATTERN2". I hope you got my point.

Comment: @KP hmm true, I missed that there could be multiple matches for pattern2 for one match of pattern1.

Comment: @KP ... so the simplest solution perhaps, we cache the cache line and see if it's already printed o.O  Looks like it should work, too bad I can't easily test it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of all the lines to print back, and eventually print them:

```
String currentHeader = scanner.nextLine();
List<String> followingLines = new ArrayList<>();
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.matches("MATCHING_PATTERN1")){
        // new header, let's print the lines if there are lines to print
        if(!followingLines.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(currentHeader);
            for(String followingLine : followingLines) {
                System.out.println(followingLine);
            }
        }
        // reset
        currentHeader = line;
        followingLines.clear();
    } else if (line.matches("MATCHING_PATTERN2")){
        followingLines.add(line);
    }
 }
 // print last one
 if(!followingLines.isEmpty()) {
     System.out.println(currentHeader);
     for(String followingLine : followingLines) {
         System.out.println(followingLine);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have run a second loop to get your result

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    String dLine = scanner.nextLine();

    if (dLine.matches("MATCHING_PATTERN1")){     
         System.out.println(dLine);
         String dLine2 = scanner.nextLine();

         while(scanner.hasNext() && dLine2.matches("MATCHING_PATTERN2"){                  
              System.out.println(dLine2);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  But won't the inner loop run until it reaches the end of the file, so it won't print the "filename.......f5" from the example, while it actually should?

Comment: That'll print "filename.......f1" from the example, while it shouldn't. Like noted earlier, it's quite hard if you can't actually test the solution :P

Comment: Also... what's gonna make the inner loop exit now?  Nothing in the condition or the body of the inner loop changes anything, so it'll loop forever if you run it on the example.

Comment: With a different log sample, like if the log has only two lines, one match for pattern1 and one match for pattern2, it won't print pattern2 because the `scanner.hasNext()` condition of the inner loop is false, since there's no next line... this inner loop thing isn't going to work, I'm afraid.

Comment: you have the pattern 2 condition in the loop itself, this will exit the loop

Comment: The `System.out.println` is supposed to change the `dLine2` somehow so it will stop matching?  Or how do you see that?

Comment: I just tested it, `"filename.+"` and `".*do not ignore.*"` as patterns. What I wrote is fact:  It'll erroneously print the first (and second) line from the example, not exit the loop but endlessly print "This test is associated with file 3 - line 1 - do not ignore it", and not print the second line if the log only has 2 lines.

The accepted answer from Riggy works (aside from the var dname/dLine) and is the most elegant imho, mine works but has some more overhead, Jean Logeart's works but has even more overhead.  So +1 to Riggy from me :)